# Dual booting Windows 10 and Debian with Windows files on both disks

Tags: linux, windows-10, debian, multi-boot

I would like to dual boot Windows 10 and Debian, however, Windows 10 is installed on my SSD with my HDD used as a secondary disk for some files and programs. I want to install Debian on the HDD (keeping the Windows files) and I wanted to know if there would be any complications with this setup.

Comment: Installing OS in two separate disks usually is the best practice. What complication do you expect? And what have you tried looking on google?

Comment: I was worried that if Debian was to the to the right of the random files, I wouldn't be able to boot from it - I am fairly new to dual-booting and Linux in general, having mostly run Linux on completely separate machines or in VMs.

Comment: The only complication i can think of is Windows can't read linux partition. You are fine to proceed with that setup.